# How can I use File::Find to create a recursive data structure?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a recursive data structure that represents a directory tree. It will be created by parsing an actual directory tree. The result should look like this simplified example:

```
$structure = [
    {
        type => 'directory',
        name => 'my_root_directory',
        items => [
            {
                type => 'file',
                name => 'image1.jpg'
            },
            {
                type => 'file',
                name => 'image2.jpg'
            },
            {
                type => 'directory',
                name => 'a_subdirectory',
                items => [
                    {
                        type => 'image',
                        name => 'image2.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the pastI have created many maintenance headaches by writing recursive functions, so this time I decided to just use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to handle the directory walking for me. Here's what I tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $structure = [];
find(\&wanted, 'my_root_directory');

sub wanted {
    my $node = {};
    if (-f) {
        $node->{type} = 'file';
        $node->{name} = $_;
    }            
    if (-d) {
        $node->{type} = 'directory',
        $node->{name} = $_;
        $node->{items} = # HELP NEEDED!
    }
    push @{$structure}, $node;
}
```

This doesn't work for two reasons:

1. I cannot assign the `$node->{items}` without duplicating the work that `File::Find` does already.
2. Even if I would populate the node's items (i.e., by calling `readdir`), the final `push` statement would simply append the node to the end `@{$structure}` array. All hierarchy would be lost.

How can I use `File::Find` to create a recursive data structure?

Comment: Can't. You could build a list of the full paths, then build the structure from that, but it might be easier to just implement the directory traversal yourself.

Comment: We have full examples in [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com) that do this. :)

Comment: I knew I'd seen something similar somewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will output the file contents in the tree structure you asked for. I used a hash `%parent_nodes` to populate references to directory nodes as they were encountered, indexed by the directory path. That made it possible to reference the appropriate parent directory node to insert new file nodes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename qw(basename);
use Data::Dumper;

my $root_dir = shift @ARGV || die "Usage: $0 DIR_PATH\n";

my %parent_nodes;
my $structure = [];
find(\&wanted, $root_dir);


sub wanted {
  my $file_name = $_;
  my $file_path = $File::Find::name;
  my $dir_path  = $File::Find::dir;

  if (-f) {
    my $node = {
      type => 'file',
      name => $file_name,
    };

    my $parent_node = $parent_nodes{$dir_path}
      || die "can't find parent node for $dir_path\n";

    push @{$parent_node->{items}}, $node;
  }
  elsif (-d) {

    my $dir_name  = basename($file_path);

    my $node = {
      type => 'directory',
      name => $dir_name,
      items => [],
    };

    if (my $parent_node = $parent_nodes{$dir_path}) {
      push @{$parent_node->{items}}, $node;
    }
    else {
      # this must be the root node
      push @$structure, $node;
    }

    $parent_nodes{$file_path} = $node;
  }
}

print Dumper($structure);
```

Comment: Thank you for this ingenious solution. It works flawlessly and answers my question exactly! However, your solution has also made me realize that File::Find is completely unsuitable for generating nested datastructures...

Answer (score 3):

How similar to your source structure do you need? Reason I ask is - something like this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(splitdir);

my %tree;

sub insert_into_tree {
    my $cursor = \%tree;
    print "$File::Find::dir = $File::Find::name\n";
    foreach my $subdir ( splitdir($File::Find::dir) ) {
        $cursor->{type} = 'directory';
        $cursor = $cursor->{subdirs}->{$subdir} ||= {};
        $cursor->{name} = $subdir;
    }
    if ( -f $File::Find::name ) {
        push( @{ $cursor->{files} }, $_ );
    }
    else { 
       $cursor -> {type} = 'directory';
    }
}

find( \&insert_into_tree, 'c:\\temp' );
print Dumper \%tree;
```

It doesn't do quite what you want, but hopefully serves to illustrate the general concept? You make a 'cursor' that's a reference to a tree position, based on the current file path. You thus build the directory tree as you go, and then insert into a 'files' array... all your files.

The thing you're brushing up against with `File::Find` though, is that *does* a recursive traversal for you (which is good, because there's gotchas) but the `wanted` function isn't inherently recursive - it's a callback, and it's fired off once per entry found, and handed 3 variables to work with.

So effectively - you still have to 'build' your tree yourself. Which is what that `$cursor` thing is doing above - it's making a pointer to your data structure based on the directory structure handed into `File::Find`.